# Better way of making javascript function a property

Tags: javascript, function, properties

I was wondering if there was a way to use the get function in the url object below to generate property without wrapping it in an anonymous function.

It may be because I am just starting to dig into JavaScript after starting with jQuery, but something seems weird about wrapping a property in a anonymous function just to concatenate a string.

**Current Object**

```
var app = {
    settings: {
        webservice: 'http://abc.com/webservice/',
        url: {
            get: function (method) {
                return app.settings.webservice + method;
            },
            caseSearch: function () {
                return this.get('GetCases');
            },
            tipSearch: function () {
                return this.get('GetTips');
            },
            propertySearch: function () {
                return this.get('GetProperty');
            }
        }
    }
};
```

**Current**

```
var url = app.settings.url.caseSearch();
```

**Proposed**

```
var url = app.settings.url.caseSearch;
```

Comment: Functions are first-class citizens. Functions are fantastic. What have you got against functions?

Comment: Depending on which versions of JS you want to support, you could always turn the `url.get` method into a *getter*. More on that [here](http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-getters-and-setters/).

Comment: In literal _Object_ syntax, [`get`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/get) is an _operator_, so I'd avoid using it without quotes if you want it as a property name.

Comment: @Mathletics nothing against functions, I just wondered if I was doing something silly.

Comment: @PaulS. thanks I will keep that in mind when using keywords, appreciate the feedback from all!